# How to customize a face on Emacs, but only when hl-line is active?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, emacs-faces

I am using Emacs 24, console (8 colors) with the Solarized theme.

[image: Emacs 24 with Solarized theme]

I want to make the comments less intrusive using:

```lisp
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face "black")
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "black")
```

That way the comments would be colored with the same color as the `hl-line` face we can see on the picture. However, when moving to a line containing comments, I would like them to be inverted (black background from the `hl-line`, normal foreground instead of black) so I can still read them.

Comment: There is `highlight-current-line-hook` in highlight-current-line mode http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/highlight-current-line.el maybe you can use it

Comment: Can you elaborate about what to do, how do I use this function ? I am far from being very competent with this technology, but I'm guessing it needs a condition which would be used to either highlight the line or not.

Comment: You change your face in a hook, `(add-hook 'highlight-current-line-hook (lambda() (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-delimiter-face "<NOT BLACK>") (set-face-foreground 'font-lock-comment-face "<NOT BLACK>")))` you can read about hooks in manual https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html

Comment: I did enable `highlight-current-line` but the hook doesn't seem to be catching anything. There are no error though.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also temporarily hide comments.  See command `hide/show-comments-toggle` in library [`hide-comnt.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/hide-comnt.el).  Bind it to a handy key --- pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code in the attached link:  [Emacs colors. why it is gray on current line? zenburn theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842144/emacs-colors-why-it-is-gray-on-current-line-zenburn-theme/17846064#17846064)

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand my issue. I want the background of the `hl-line` to be black, and the foreground of comments too. However when comments are on the `hl-line` I want them to revert to the standard color (so I can read them). Also I cannot use 256 colors, I'm stuck with 8.

Comment: Try out some of the code in the answers of the attached link in your .emacs file, and then report back if you still have any questions.  The original poster stated that `nil` for the foreground lets the other colors shine through.  If you want to alter the behavior of hl-line, then you will need to look at its source code.

Comment: What you linked doesn't help me. The provided solutions use background, foreground and bold'ness only.

Comment: `nil` foreground lets the other definitions shine through.  If your goal is to suppress all other font definitions everywhere `except` on the current line being viewed, well, you will likely need to substantially modify the source code of hl-line.el

Comment: Now I see what you meant. My goal is to suppress existing foreground rules for the comments which are on the current line **only**.

Comment: Perhaps you could write something special to alter the default behavior:  "By default the whole line is highlighted.  The range of highlighting can be changed by defining an appropriate function as the buffer-local value of `hl-line-range-function'."

Comment: With a foreground `highlight` setting of a color (e.g., black), very little else ever shines through except something like flyspell misspelled words.  For example, in `emacs-lisp-mode`, nothing shines through on the highlighted line -- i.e., the foreground of everything is black / bold, and the background is grey.